# How can I create a Boxfuse environment with a non-default VPC

Tags: playframework, cloudcaptain

I work in a company that has an AWS account, and we want to deploy all our Play apps in the same AWS region (say us-east-1). This region does not have a "default" VPC and in any case, we prefer to deploy our apps in an existing VPC already set up by our IT department. How can I set Boxfuse to use another VPC then the default, from the web interface (https://console.cloudcaptain.sh)? If that's not possible, how could we do this by command line?

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new environment with a non-default VPC by clicking "Create Environment" on the "Overview" tab in the Boxfuse Console. You can then deploy to that VPC by specifying your new environment.

Example: `boxfuse run -env=mynewenv`

Comment: Thank you; I was able to create a new environment with a specific VPC, but deploying my app fails (although deploying the same app on the 'prod' or 'test' environments works well).

Comment: Please get in touch at hello at boxfuse dot com with the details of the error you are getting